# find command with regex to find directories

Tags: linux, find, path-finding

I have the following linux find command that gives a base path then also searches if there are any directories that contain the name 3.7.1

In my base path /some/folder/path/folder1 i would like to change folder1 into a regular expression something like folder[1-3] how can I do this?

```
# working command
find /some/folder/path/folder1/another_folder -type d -name "3.7.1*" -ls

# would like to use some regular expresion on folder1-3
find /some/folder/path/folder[1-3]/another_folder -type d -name "3.7.1*" -ls


error I am seeing:  /folder[1-3]/another_folder/': No such file or directory
```

Comment: That means there are no matches. Note that it matches as a shell glob and not as a grep style regex

Comment: So...  What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct syntax already:

```
find /some/folder/path/folder[1-3] -type d -name "3.7.1*" -ls
```

Comment: actually this command gives error. it thinks the folder name is literally folder[1-3] and its not using a regex.

Comment: This is the error [1-3/': No such file or directory

Comment: I from some of the examples I seen i thought I would need to give some regex switch to let the command know im using a regex

Comment: @Matt - did you include the closing square bracket in the command? Also, if you have errors, your question is a GREAT place to put them, so that people answering know how far you've gotten.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I have included the closing square bracket. Also I updated the question as after folder1 I have another folder so the path really would look like this /some/folder/path/folder[1-3]/another_folder but still when I give this I run into an error.

Comment: Here is the error I see. I think the last one was just a poor copy paste job. 
  /folder[1-3]/another_folder/': No such file or directory

Comment: @Matt Please consider posting the actual code you use instead of something you believe will show roughly the same error. Shell scripts are exceptionally finicky and seemingly insignificant changes like different spacing has a huge effect. If the names contain things you don't want on the internet, please take the time to create a new directory structure to test against.